# FormulaR1C1 doesn't work with SUMME

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, excel-formula

The FormulaR1C1 Method doesn't work as it's supposed to.

```
objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Dim Formula As String
    Formula = "=SUMME(Z1S1;Z2S1)"
    For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
        objWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = 5
        objWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "Text"
        objWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = Formula
    Next
```

This should give me 10 in the third column 5 times, but it doesn't. I even tried it with:

```
Formula = "=SUMME(Z[0]S[-2];Z[1]S[-2])"
```

but that doesn't work either. The Loop just breaks when coming to the assigment line :( . If I try it with

```
Formula = "=SUMME(Z1S1,Z2S1)"
```

It executes completely but it doesn't work for excel because then it says  =SUMME('Z1S1';'Z2S1') in the Excel Field

Comment: What are the errors when it breaks?

Comment: There are no Errors :( It just finishes when it comes to objWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = Formula

Comment: I've just tried, this `"=SUM(R2C1,R2C2)"` and it's fine, im not sure if you need to put the 1st 2 in as values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1Local property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838568.aspx) if you plan to use a string that contains non-EN-US function. VB.Net **expects** a EN-US formula and will translate that to the regional language of the worksheet.

```
Formula = "=SUM(A1, B2)"
'or depending on your requiements,
Formula = "=SUM(A1:B2)"
.Formula = Formula

Formula = "=SUM(R1C1, R2C2)"
'or depending on your requiements,
Formula = "=SUM(R1C1:R2C2)"
.FormulaR1C1 = Formula

Formula = "=SUMME(Z1S1;Z2S1)"
'or depending on your requirements,
Formula = "=SUMME(Z1S1:Z2S1)"
.FormulaLocalR1C1 = Formula
```

Don't confuse xlA1 cell references with xlR1C1 references. **R23** would mean Cells(23, 18) in xlA1 and 23:23 in xlR1C1.

Note that using the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)  or [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx) enforces the use of a comma (EN-US standard) instead of a semicolon as a system list separator.

---

<sub>[Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)

[Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx)

[Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx)

[Range.FormulaR1C1Local property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838568.aspx)</sub>

Comment: Putting a constant (e.g. **5** or **"text"** in as a formula defaults to being put in as the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) since they are not formulas.

Comment: fwiw, it is never a good idea to repurpose the name of a reserved word, property or method as a variable. Using **myFormula* as the string would have been  infinitely more preferable. Yes, they are different and may be completely disparate to you but it can only lead of confusion when others view your code. I mean, seriously, you even proper cased the var.

Comment: True of course, although I'm not OP, just interested ;) I recently had an issue with German R1C1/Z1S1 references myself so I was curious. (ps: you mixes up the last line, should be `.FormulaR1C1Local`. Now I'm done!)

Comment: Can't ask another question yet so Jeeped I hope you might help me here :3; I got a new Problem with : destWorkbook.Worksheets("Intern").Cells(SumIndex, j + 8).NumberFormatLocal = "0,00" The fields which should be formatted get formatted with custom #.000

Comment: `"0.00"` should work as a format mask for EN-US or DE-DE I believe. The laptop I'm on doesn't have enough languages loaded to fully test. May be just use the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx).

Comment: @Jeeped apart from the last line and the extra `)` in the 4th-to-last line it looks what I would expect to work properly. I don't have German installed either so I can't test it^^ I agree on deleting these comments...